# How to Show and Hide Element With Checkbox Status in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

Can you please let me know how I can show and Hide an element in angular? in following example I want to initially hide the `#item-details` and show it if check box checked or Hide if un-check

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<body>
<div class="container" ng-controller="checkController">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2"><input type="checkbox" name="item" value="new" />Add New Item <br /></div>

<div class="col-md-6" id="item-details" ng-show="">
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js">/script>
<script>
   var app = angular.module('app', [])
   .controller('checkController', function() { });
    this.
});

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First assign an model to the check box

```
<div class="col-md-2"><input type="checkbox" name="item" value="new" ng-model="checked" />Add New Item <br /></div>
```

then simply assign the same model value to item-details in ng-show

```
<div class="col-md-6" id="item-details" ng-show="checked">
```

you are done

Comment: Hi maddy I did you said ath this http://plnkr.co/edit/K9yHOF0at93ECuGPxjAy?p=preview but it still not working

Comment: As I said I do not want to show the `#item-details` on load

Comment: look at your controller name , you are using wrong controller name in html you had define "checkController" and in angularjs you have create "mainController" ,just change the controller name and it will start working

Comment: there is a lot wrong in the plunkler you had wriiten ,i had updated it ,it is now working :D

Comment: so we do not need to pass any thing in mainController? I mean any function or something?

Comment: no nothing ,model will take care of everything ,but this things only works with checkbox and radio buttons ,for doing toggle on button click you need to define function in angularjs, but that is also relatively simple.

Comment: great thanks just one more question, please? In case of getting the value of checkbox? or radio? is this still enough?

Comment: yes simply access the value in angularjs as $scope.checked .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90458/discussion-between-suffii-and-maddygoround).

Answer (score 3):

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/f2k4MhTA4YFfFegEzNbV?p=preview)

```
 var app = angular.module('app', []);
 app.controller('checkController', function($scope) {
    $scope.hide = false;
    $scope.checkboxClick = function() {
      $scope.hide = !$scope.hide;
    };

  });
```

HTML:

```
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="checkController" class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-click="checkboxClick()" value="new" name="item" /> Add New Item
        <br />
      </div>
      <div ng-show="hide" id="item-details" class="col-md-6">
        <div aria-label="..." role="group" class="btn-group">
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Left</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Middle</button>
          <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">Right</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In one way or the other, the ng-show is not working but I use the ng-if as a work around which work perfectly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<body>
<div class="container" ng-controller="checkController">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-2"><input type="checkbox" name="item" ng-model="item" value="new" />Add New Item <br /></div>

<div class="col-md-6" id="item-details" ng-if="item == true">
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

hope is helps thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <div class="container" ng-controller="checkController">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2"><input type="checkbox" name="item" value="new" ngmodel="checked" ngchecked="checked == '1'"/>Add New Item <br /></div>

    <div class="col-md-6" id="item-details" ngshow = "checked == '1'">
    <div class="btn-gr`enter code here`oup" role="group" aria-label="...">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

Just do above
```